# Should I unit test *what* or *how* for composite functions?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have functions `f` and `g`, which already have a collection of unit tests ensuring that their behavior is correct for some known inputs-output pairs (plus exception handling, etc).

Now I'm creating the function `h()`, as follows:

```
def h(x):
    return f(x) + g(2*x)
```

What's a good approach for unit testing this function? Would this change if `h()` was substantially more complex?

---

*My thoughts so far:*

I see two possibilities for testing `h()`.

#### 1. Testing if `h()` is doing the correct "plumbing"

Mock out `f()` so that it returns `y_0` when called with input `x_0`; mock `g()` so that it returns `z_0` when called with input `2*x_0`. Then check that calling `h(x_0)` returns `y_0+z_0`.

*Advantages*:

- Very simple to implement the test.
- Can quickly find bugs where I incorrectly connected the outputs of `f` and `g`, or where I called them with wrong arguments (say, calling `g(x)` instead of `g(2*x)` in `h()`).

*Disadvantages*:

- This is testing *how*, not *what* `h()` should do. If later I want to refactor `h()`, then I'll probably need to rewrite these types of tests.
- If the plumbing specified by the test does not produce the intended high-level behavior for `h()`, then these tests won't catch this error. For example, maybe the correct plumbing was supposed to be `f(-x) + g(2*x)`, and I made it wrong both in the function definition and in the test definition.

#### 2. Testing **what** `h()` should do

Let's say that the purpose of `h()` is to compute the sum of primes below the given argument. In this case, a natural test suite for `h()` would involve testing it with known input-output pairs. Something that makes sure that, for instance, `h(1)=2`, `h(2)=5`, `h(5)=28`, etc, not caring about **how** `h()` is computing these numbers.

*Advantages*:

- This type of test checks that `h()` is indeed following its intended high-level behavior. Any plumbing mistakes that alter this will be caught.
- Refactoring `h()` will probably not necessitate changing the test suite, and will even be easier, since the tests help us guarantee that the behavior of the function doesn't change.

*Disadvantages*:

- In this simple example it's easy to produce such pairs because the mapping that `h()` performs is not very complicated (just sum the `n` first primes). However, for a very complicated `h()`, my only option for producing such pairs might be me to come up with an input `x` and compute the correct output by hand. This doesn't seem reasonable if `h` is very complicated.
- Since coming up with known input-output pairs requires me to compute what `f()` and `g()` will produce given a certain input, there will probably be some duplication of effort, since I already spent some time doing that when creating the unit tests for these functions.

---

*Related question*: [Unit testing composite functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654729/unit-testing-composite-functions).

This question is at first glance very similar to mine. However, the two most voted answers present completely different approaches to the problem (the two approaches I mentioned above). My question is an attempt in clarifying the pros/cons of each approach (and perhaps learn other approaches), and potentially establish which is best overall. If no approach is best in all cases, I would like to understand in which cases one should use each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you interpret `h`:

1. Is it something that represents the combination of `f` and `g`, regardless of how `f` and `g` may behave in the future? Then you test the plumbing.
2. Is it something that produces a value, which *at the moment* you compute using `f` and `g` but could use an alternate implementation? Then test the output against the expected value given the input.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable, thanks! Regarding point 2, how would you come up with known input-output pairs? Would you compute the expected output by hand, verifying what `f` and `g` should do for a certain input and then summing the result? Doesn't this lead to a duplication of efforts?

Comment: Ultimately, yes. Testing is not about efficiency; it's about verifying that `h` produces the correct result. Normally, you don't compute the expected value in the test; you hard code it. The point is that no matter *how* you implement `h`, your test should simply validate that an input of `x` produces an output of `y`, however you choose to determine `y`.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to generate your expected output using the *exact* same method `h` uses, because then all you are doing is verifying that `h` is executed properly, not that `h` is *implemented* properly. The problem with something like `assert h(x) == f(x) * g(2*x)` should be obvious. That test will pass, even if `f(x) * g(2*x)` is *not* the correct way to implement `h`.

Comment: Interesting points. Regarding hard-coding, yes, this is what I meant (I would compute the result by hand, and hard-code it). Regarding how to generate the expected output, this is a bit tricky for me. In my current context, the only way I can think of computing the expected value of `h` is by computing `f(x) * g(2*x)`. Maybe this is a sign that I should see `h` as just the combination of `f` and `g`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, you don't want to duplicate your test logic.

You might not want to include `f` and `g` logic inside your test for `h`.
In this case, mocking is well suited because it will allow you to only test `h`.
If `f` changes and has regression, then tests for `h` won't fail because its logic is still valid.

The problem of doing this is that you add more layers of (unit) tests.
The benefit however is that you completely isolate your tests and the logic is only tested where it should be.

As for everything, there is a balance to find. But if your logic is complex and include multiples collaborators (like `f` and `g`), then mocking can reduce the test complexity.

If you're familiar with TDD, it's directly related to Mockist vs Classicist.
If you have time, I suggest you to look at these [videos](https://youtu.be/XHnuMjah6ps) about Outside-In TDD. You'll learn a lot.

Comment: Hi Arnaud, thanks for your time. I don't think I really understood your recommendation. Are you saying that if my code is very complex then I should be testing *how* its doing things as opposed to *what* it is doing? That is, I should test that it is calling the right mocks with the correct inputs, instead of finding known input-output pairs?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that if your logic is complex, you want to separate the concerns and responsibilities.     Therefore instead of having one single component to test, you have multiple smaller components that have collaborators.     Each component can be unit tested by mocking its collaborators and asserting the correct interactions.    Then you add an acceptance test that won't use mocks and will test the entire system.